# Give value to radio button php and save to sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a little problem that i have been struggling for the last 16hrs I can find a solution for this... I really really need some help please...

I have the form which is generated by a query based on users ID...

```
ID-1 Question 1
 rad-btn ID-1 group 1 value 0 answer x
 rad-btn ID-2 group 1 value 0 answer x
 rad-btn ID-3 group 1 value 0 answer x

ID-2 Question 2
 rad-btn ID-4 group 2 value 0 answer x
 rad-btn ID-5 group 2 value 0 answer x
 rad-btn ID-6 group 2 value 0 answer x

ID-4 Question 3
 rad-btn ID-6 group 4 value 0 answer x
 rad-btn ID-7 group 4 value 0 answer x
 rad-btn ID-8 group 4 value 0 answer x
```

to get that "form" I use an sql as follow

```
$padreQR = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ph_sec_preguntas WHERE s_codigo = '$secc1' ");

while ($arrayP = mysql_fetch_array($padreQR)) {
    $preguntasPP = $arrayP['pregunta_id'];
    $preguntass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preguntas_p WHERE question_id = '$preguntasPP' ");
    while ($q1 = mysql_fetch_array($preguntass)) {
        $qid = $q1['question_id'];
        $pp1 = $q1['question'];
        $er = $qid;
        echo '"<h3>' . $pp1 . '</h3>'; // Ya tenemos las preguntas segun el usuario
        $rrr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM respuestas WHERE question_id = '$qid' ");
        while ($arrayRR = mysql_fetch_array($rrr)) {
            $respuestas = $arrayRR['answer'];
            $correcto = $arrayRR['correct'];


            echo '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="' . $er . '" value="' . $correcto . '">' . $respuestas . '</label>';
        }
    }
};
```

it may be not the best way to do it, for it works...

So what I need is to save this information but not all, I only need:

```
userID, questionID, and the answer that was selected
```

my problem is, how do I get the selected radio button? and get the ID from that answer, I don't need to know the value, just which radio button was select and so I can get the ID from that button, that way I can save it to the sql, the ID came from the SQL, the value will always be 1 or 0...

Right now I'm only showing 3 questions with multiple choices, but the idea is to have about 20 questions in a single page...

Thank you for taking the time to read my question...

Comment: Please see about JOINs

Answer (score 0):

Simply set each Value to ID, and You will know from $_POST array what options have been marked.

Something like this:

```
echo '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="preguntas[' . $pregunta_id . ']" value="' . $respuesta_id . '">' . $respuestas . '</label>';
```

And then when posting this to Your php script, you will get an array of answers.

```
foreach($_POST['preguntas'] as $pregunta_id => $respuesta_id){
   echo "RESPUESTA A PREGUNTA NUMERO $pregunta_id ERA $respuesta_id <br />\n";
}
```

Something like that...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, please bear with me, would care to elaborate your question with an example?, please... I'm still learning php and sql, I have manage to get this far by reading some books, it's kind of  limited when it came to examples... thank you again...

Comment: I would need the database tables (de preguntas y respuestas) structure for working example.

Comment: Hello, thank you, table of "preguntas" ID, questionID, question, that's it, question has the actual "question" Whats your name?" sort of questions... questionID is a int(11), then we have the table "respuestas" ID, questionID, answer, where answer is the actual answer, and the "questionID" is the same number as in the table "preguntas", now, after the user has answer the information has to be saved in another table called in this case "user_answers" cols, ID, questionID, answerID, uderID, ... thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this form:

```
<form action="test.php">
    <input type="radio" name="quest" value="q1" /> Pregunta 1<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq1" value="a1" /> Respuesta 1.1<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq1" value="a2" /> Respuesta 1.2<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq1" value="a3" /> Respuesta 1.3<br/>
            <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="quest" value="q2" /> Pregunta 2<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq2" value="a1" /> Respuesta 2.1<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq2" value="a2" /> Respuesta 2.2<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq2" value="a3" /> Respuesta 2.3<br/>
            <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="quest" value="q3" /> Pregunta 3<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq3" value="a1" /> Respuesta 3.1<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq3" value="a2" /> Respuesta 3.2<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="ansq3" value="a3" /> Respuesta 3.3<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

On **test.php** you will have something like this:

```
<?php 
$pregunta = $_GET['quest'];
$respuesta = $_GET['ans'.$pregunta]; //Add the question to the index to filter the answer.
    echo "Seleccionaste la pregunta: $pregunta y la respuesta: $respuesta";
?>
```

You can change the method of this form to POST if security needed.

Now, with those values you can easily save them to the DB. For that, I recommend you to learn about how [prepared statements](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) works. Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated, try to avoid them. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.